# How to remove black outlines on buttons after clicking on form in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am making a flat GUI in windows forms.. i know i cant just ignore and leave tab indexing and i have included it. when i am using tab in my program to select control,a black outline appears on controls(as in this pic). what i want is to remove this outlining when i mouse-click anywhere because it seems Ugly if i am not using my keyboard.

[how can i remove this outline on flat button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvj07.png)

can you suggest me how can i achieve this target?

Comment: In order to remove the outline you will have to remove the input focus from the button.

Comment: Can you try `button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;`

Comment: @Berkay thanks, but it seems nothing noticeable happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hiding the focus cue by creating your own button:

```
public class ButtonEx : Button {

  protected override bool ShowFocusCues {
    get {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```